# African passport+EU national ID

Tags: passports, morocco, eu-id-card

As per title, I'm a dual national, and I'd like to travel in Morocco with Moroccan passport and Italy with national ID (or passport in case required).

So basically, as far as dual citizenship is concerned I'm allowed to enter in and exit from Morocco with Moroccan passport and enter and exit from Italy with national ID, by showing Moroccan passport at check-in for flight towards Morocco and national ID at check-in for flight towards Italy. It seems fair enough because by checking Timatic, this procedure seems OK.

I've been told that this doesn't work out in Morocco by a few friends. I don't understand why because many dual citizens travel with 2 passports or mixed documentation every day. Why can't this work out for Morocco? Dual citizenship is not illegal in Morocco.

I'm asking this because I want to leave more space on my EU passport. I don't want the Moroccan government to know things about me like having another citizenship. I don't like an institution knowing my status or my affairs abroad.

Edit: According to Timatic, I can travel this way, but many Moroccans say otherwise. I do not know honestly if Morocco is a very particular case, because even US-Mexicans or US-Italians, US-Brits, Anglo-Australians and so forth may travel this way. I do not understand why I can't. Very simple.

Comment: I added some paragraph breaks and removed what I felt was redundant information. The longer your explanation is, the less likely it is that people will read through the whole thing. Feel free to revert my changes if you feel that it's too much.

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moroccan_nationality_law#Dual_citizenship, Morocco has no prohibition against dual citizenship.

Comment: Have you done military service in Morocco? Not having done so is the only thing I can think of that might be a problem.

Comment: It's not clear what your question here is. You know what the usual answer to the situation is, but you have decided it must be wrong because your friends say it is. But then why are you asking _us_ rather than _your friends_ why they think we're wrong and they are right? You're not going to get a different answer here just by asserting that your question is not a duplicate of the questions it in fact duplicates.

Comment: @Michael Hampton it has nothing do to with my concern. Military service was reintroduced recently, but students and residents abroad or workers are exempt. This is not the issue.

Comment: @user33954: The only new thing in your case is that you know some people who claim the normal answer does not apply to you. If you want to know why they think that, **why are you asking us and not them?**

Comment: To have an answer from experienced travelers and also show it to them, since they also claim that I utter b***sh*t with this idea of traveling in this way.

Comment: By the way I don't want "it to be wrong" otherwise I wouldn't be asking here in the first place after asking them and seeing many threads on the matter. If I don't know the exact answer I'll ask, I don't want to waste your time or others' time, and if you feel annoyed by my question, do not answer, simple. Ignore me, what else do you want me to say?

Comment: You turned out to be a philosophical reprimander against me, jeez.

Comment: Are your friends dual citizens of Morocco and another country? What is their authority so say this can/can't be done? Carry both passports. Exit Italy with ITA one, enter AND exit Morocco on MAR one and only show your ITA passport when checking in/boarding the flight to Italy and at passport control in Italy.

Comment: I removed the "do not flag as duplicate" paragraph. That is inappropriate; the community will vote to close as a duplicate if it feels it is warranted.

Comment: @Henninh Malkhom I already knew that, but I don't want to register it with Morocco anyway. It's not their business if I hold another passport.

Answer (score -1):

The difference between EU national ID and Italian passport is that you can freely travel within EEU/CH with your Italian/EU National ID, but that ID is not a valid document for Moroccan government (they need a proof that you are leaving to Italy legally) or anywhere outside EEU/CH. Your Italian passport, on the other end, is. Thus, the Moroccan government will need to see your Italian passport on departure.

For reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_identity_cards_in_the_European_Economic_Area

Comment: In Timatic I have found this results with departure from Morocco https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external-result/oV06H3SWlG1zYQgZ_xOs1MZ2ps82. I have put National ID as documentation

Comment: But the thing is that the national ID has to be valid for the destination country, because in Morocco I would have entered with Moroccan pass, and the ID would be sufficient for the airline. I find it meaning less that an authority can question a paper that grants the right to go to the other country if that other country accepts it in the first place

Comment: You seem to already have your answer and are sticking to it, so why even ask the people on here? Try using it and let us know how it goes

Comment: @user33954 you can sure try your luck, but as a dual citizen myself I am just telling you how it usually works.

Comment: @Ozzy The thing is that I know a Saudi-German citizen who basically uses only his nationals IDs to travel between German and Saudi. This is why I'm trying to ask, to refute all of those who say that and not using Italian passport to enter a country I'm also a national of. It is just principle and saving space in pages. That's all.

Comment: Other western countries don't do that. They don't have officials who at the exit, verify whether a their own citizen has a visa for a certain country. Only in Morocco there's such a thing.

Comment: Then why don't you carry your Italian passport with you, but only show it if they reject your EU id. Problem solved? :)

Comment: No one is going to stamp your Italian passport. Just carry it. As a citizen Italy won't stamp you on exit  or entry. Use your Moroccan one to enter and exit Morrocco. When they ask you where your visa is for Italy just show them the card or passport. You're complicating things

Comment: @Andrey yes thank you, using two passports is correct, but by noticing Timatic's response in the meanwhile and thinking about It one can enter the Schengen area with ID also from outside schengen, of course, after having cleared checks in the other country he came from. Meaning, after having used an EU passport for exiting, let's say, CANADA, I can come back and enter Italy only with ID.

Comment: @ Andrey I'd definitely do that, I was just pointing out Timatic's outcome in this scenario.